# How can I force firefox to display all page specific font?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, firefox-extensions

I chrome browser I use [Change font family](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aabledekpjmoghdjnpnhfkfpmjifklpb) to force chrome to do this, but I in firefox I didn't find any way to do this.
unboxing allow page to choose their font in Firefox doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few solutions:

1. Just go to *Tools>Options*, go to the *content* tab, and click on the *Advanced* button. Once there, set the font styles the way you like them, and uncheck the *Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of my selections above* option.
2. Use the *View>Page Style* menu and select *No Style*
3. Set the fonts for individual pages or many pages at once with Stylish (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/)

Answer (score 0):

The CSS code for Stylish would be something like

```
html * {font-family:Arial !important;}
```